# xfce not working in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, xfce, desktop-environment

I installed xfce in freebsd in Oracle VB and I have followed all the step  downloaded xorg,xfce,slim,slim-themes edited `/etc/rc.conf` added dbus_enable="YES", hald_enable="YES" slim_enable="YES" and in `~/.xinitrc` added exec startxfce4 but it is not working. During the startup it shows messages:

[image] which are in image attached.

When I run startx command it shows error[image]

Comment: You have followed _the_ steps.  Which steps in particular?  There isn't a question in your text above - merely a rant.  How can anyone answer this without knowing what you've tried so far?  Please read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on asking a good question.

Comment: @garethTheRed thanks, for your suggestion, I updated the question

Comment: Is “hald_enalbe” a typo in reality or just the question?

Comment: You might correct it before people get more confused.

Comment: Which version of FreeBSD do you use? Since was replaced with devd and hald is deprecated.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens 10.4

Comment: `.xinitrc` is used by `startx` command, so for it to work log in and then run `startx`. If you want X server to start automatically on system load, then `slim_enable="YES"` should've do the trick. Check slim's configuration or logs.

Comment: It appears to me you have not read the Handbook on this. You are also using an old version of FreeBSD which currently sits at 11.1.

Comment: @arrowd, it is giving error I uploaded image above

Comment: Well, it is X configuration problem and the error message is clear. Since you are running virtualbox, you shouldn't need any xorg.conf, X should automatically pick up right driver. Try installing `virtualbox-ose-additions` package too.